# how to use pycurl if requested data is sometimes gzipped, sometimes not?

Tags: python, http, gzip, libcurl, pycurl

I'm doing this to fetch some data:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.ENCODING, 'gzip') 
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 10)   
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)

xml = StringIO()

c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, xml.write )

c.perform()
c.close()
```

My urls are typically of this sort:

```
http://host/path/to/resource-foo.xml
```

Usually I get back 302 pointing to:

```
http://archive-host/path/to/resource-foo.xml.gz
```

Given that I have set FOLLOWLOCATION, and ENCODING gzip, everything works great.

The problem is, sometimes I have a URL which does not result in a redirect to a gzipped resource.  When this happens, `c.perform()` throws this error:

```
pycurl.error: (61, 'Error while processing content unencoding: invalid block type')
```

Which suggests to me that pycurl is trying to gunzip a resource that is not gzipped.

Is there some way I can instruct pycurl to figure out the response encoding, and gunzip or not as appropriate?  I have played around with using different values for `ENCODING`, but so far no beans.

The pycurl docs seems to be a little lacking.  :/

thx!

Comment: Isn't curl able to autodecode? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6711166/582917

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If worst comes to worst, you could omit the ENCODING 'gzip', set HTTPHEADER to {'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip'}, [check the response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472179/how-to-read-the-header-with-pycurl) for "Content-Encoding: gzip" and if it's present, gunzip the response yourself.

Comment: thanks @Piskvor!  I think I must have missed your answer here back in '09.