# Get Request Using PyCurl after logging into website

Tags: python, pycurl

After doing a post to log into my website, I try to do a get on my the site and I get a bunch of garbage  "�0������`&)��붋...." instead of the data from my site. Why is that? How do I fix that?

Comment: Code, please? (15 characters)

Comment: Looks like you may have a bad content-type header, esp. the text encoding part.  How's that header, exactly?  And (given a browser that guesses the encoding correctly as it lets you see your post) what does the browser day the encoding is?

Answer (score 4):

Obviously a dead thread, but if anyone else stumbles across this, funky data like that is most likely compressed with zlib or gzip.  If you are using pycurl, this should do the trick:

```
import pycurl

ch = pycurl.Curl()
ch.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://example.com')
ch.setopt(pycurl.ENCODING, '')
ch.perform()
```

Setting the [ENCODING](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTACCEPTENCODING) option to an empty string sets the 'Accept-Encoding' headers to all encodings supported by libcurl and tells libcurl to decode the response data.  OP was probably setting the headers manually and libcurl wasn't expecting encoded data.

Comment: Is pycurl able to know when the data is encoded or not. What if we set the ENCODING, but it's not gzipped, can it autodetect whether it should decompress or not. Sometimes the data could be deflate too!